# Determine RESTEasy response type at runtime

Tags: response, resteasy

The webservice I need to call returns "two different response objects" at runtime without any header or meta data to distinguish them.

The only way is reading and casting the input stream at the client side. I am wondering how is this possible with rest easy?

Answer (score 0):

We have to define a message body reader and in there we can decide which object to stream. This is an example code:

```
ResteasyProviderFactory restProviderFactory = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();
RegisterBuiltin.register(restProviderFactory);
restProviderFactory.addMessageBodyReader(MyRestResponseReader.class);

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager());
ClientExecutor executor = new ApacheHttpClientExecutor(httpClient);
MyRestInterface client = ProxyFactory.create(MyRestInterface.class, url, executor);

ClientResponse<Object> res =  client.get(request);
Object output = res.getEntity();


public class MyRestResponseReader implements MessageBodyReader<Object> {
    public boolean isReadable(Class clazz, Type type, Annotation[] annptation, MediaType mediaType) {
            return  Object.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
        }

public Object readFrom(Class clazz, Type type, Annotation[] annotation, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap map, InputStream inputStream)
        throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try{
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String allLines = "";
            String line = "";
            while( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                allLines = allLines + line;
            }

            if(allLines.contains("...")){
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyResponseA.class);
                Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                StringReader reader = new StringReader(allLines);
                return (MyResponseA) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);                
            }else if (allLines.contains("validationResponse")){
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyResponseB.class);
                Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                StringReader reader = new StringReader(allLines);
                return (MyResponseB) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);                
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public interface MyRestInterface {

    @POST
    @Consumes({"application/xml"})
    @Produces({"application/xml"})
    public ClientResponse<Object> get(ValidationRequest req);

}
```